# VBA delete sheet throws runtime error 9, but still deletes sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've got some prehistorical code that I have to check if it is still working with Office 2016. With Office 2013 it is working like a charm, but now with the new version I get an error. That's what I'm trying:

In Workbook A I've got a worksheet WS-A that I want to copy to a new Workbook B. Before that I'm creating a copy of WS-A (called WA-A-Copy) in Workbook A and make some changes. Afterwards I copy WS-A-Copy to a new Workbook B (creating WS-B). At last I want to remove WS-A-Copy from the original workbook A, but when I try to delete this sheet, I get a runtime error 9 (Subscript out of range).

```
WorkbookA = ActiveWorkbook.Name
WS-A-Copy = ActiveSheet.Name
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy

'go to WS-A-Copy in workbook B and add a copy of the values and formats
WS-B = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets(WS-B).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select

'Go back to Workbook A and delete WS-A-Copy
Windows(WorkbookA).Activate

If SheetExists(WS-A-Copy) Then
    Sheets(WS-A-Copy).Delete <-- Runtime Error 9
End If
```

I'm already checking if I'm using the right Workbook A (debug mode - type "? activeworkbook.Name" in the Immediate Window right before the error occurs). 
I'm also checking if the Sheet exists in the current Workbook.
So both are true.

But why do I get this runtime error? And why does this sheet WS-A-Copy still get deleted in Workbook A? And why is this a problem in Office 2016, but with Office 2013 it's fine?

Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you get through variables named like that? My excel 2013 compiler wouldn't pass them

Comment: For your own sake, fully qualify the workbook variables and dont use select or activate.  Its probable that this is contributing to the error

Comment: @user3598756 : I've just changed the variable names to make the code more readable

Comment: Step through your code and use Immediate Window to query `?ActiveWorkbook.Name` and `?Activesheet.Name` right before any relevant workbook or worksheet action (copy, paste ...). This will make you both aware of what all that selecting/activating is actually leading you to and willing to switch to fully qualified ranges use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simplify you code by setting references to the objects instead of referencing them by name.  Changing this  `WS-A-Copy = ActiveSheet.Name` to `Set WS-A-Copy = ActiveSheet` will allow you to delete the worksheet without referencing the workbook that it is in.  `WS-A-Copy.Delete`

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't solve the problem itself, but this old code needs some fresh lines that are from this century. By doing this I've discovered the real error some lines further down, where an illegal worksheet was referenced